# Spark RDD fault tolerance

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

my question is " **Does fault tolerance in Spark RDD happens automatically or do we need to replay the transformation on the lost partitions ?** "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will recompute lost partitions automatically.

Comment: Thanks Simon. But I read in some blog that if in case we lose any partition of RDD, we need to replay the transformation on that partition. Is that correct?

Comment: When you run your code on a cluster with 8 nodes. Then your RDD is distributed. Now it can happen that you lose a node. The partitions of the RDD on that one node are lost. The developer do not have to handle that case. Spark will automatically recompute (replay) the lost partitions on a different node. But your input data should be available on all nodes, replicated in hdfs or available on the master node with nfs.